# get_grade() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, oop

I was trying to Imitate a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeznW_7DlB0)

I'm facing the problem whenever I run the code I got an error for the 'self' argument * the first line should be with no indent but for StackOverflow I indeed the whole code with 4 taps.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade  # 0 - 100

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

class Course:
    def __init__(self, name, max_students):
        self.name = name
        self.max_students = max_students
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students:
            self.students.append(student)
            return True
        return False

    def get_average_grade(self):
        value = 0
        for student in self.students:
            value += Student.get_grade()

        return value / len(self.students)

s1 = Student("Tim", 19, 95)
s2 = Student("Bill", 19, 75)
s3 = Student("Jill", 19, 65)

course = Course("Science", 2)
course.add_student(s1)
course.add_student(s2)
print(course.get_average_grade())
```

Comment: Typo: `Student.get_grade()` should be `student.get_grade()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to lower-case `Student` to `student` since `get_grade()` is an instance method ;)

```
value += student.get_grade()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a simple mistake, `Student.get_grade()` should be `student.get_grade()` - you want to call the method on the object, not the class.

Note: this is why people will tell you to name your variables all lower case and your classes with CamelCase - of course you can still miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method that requires the instance to be passed as a parameter.

Try:

```
for student in self.students:
            value += Student.get_grade(student)
```

Comment: Everyone else's comment is right, I just gave you an alternate way to do it.